# LINQ timed out while the same query works great in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

```
 Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  
 The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation 
 or the server is not responding.

        var items = dataContext.function1(sid);                
        var sortBy = Int32.Parse(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        var sortAsc = Request["sSortDir_0"] == "asc";                

        /* All items after filtering */
        var totalItems = items.Count();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["iDisplayStart"]))
            items = items.Skip(Int32.Parse(Request["iDisplayStart"]));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["iDisplayLength"]))
            items = items.Take(Int32.Parse(Request["iDisplayLength"]));
foreach (var cres in items)
            {
...
...
```

When I run the SAME query in the SQL query program I get result within seconds, and in LINQ it takes forever and fails.

What can cause this???

Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach an SQL profiler, and post the exact SQL which is executed in each case? Can you include the LINQ statement too?

Comment: Well, what is the query? And what type of LINQ is it,

Comment: I ran the profiler. I dont see the query in the profiler. The query runs in 0.5seconds in SQL! LINQ 4.0

Comment: Can you post your linq query, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to answer your question.

Comment: I saw in the profiler the COUNT() query, but i dont see the foreach one...

Comment: How did you see Count() query in SQl profiler? You are not sending Count() query to sql?

Comment: On which line the timeout is, on items.Count(); or foreach (var cres in items)?

Comment: Sometimes it was on Count() and sometimes on foreach

Comment: You have already solve the problem by restarting SQL Server service, possible some resource allocation issue, just keep an eye on server itself.

Comment: I restarted the SQL Server service and its working.
What can cause this???

Comment: Cosmic rays, randomness - or perhaps a bad query plan that got cached... So to clarify: is all well again now?

Comment: Yes... I just had to reset it... the same query with different parameters worked all the time. only a specific params settings caused this to stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the SQL Server service and its working.
What can cause this???

Comment: Cosmic rays, randomness - or perhaps a bad query plan that got cached... So to clarify: is all well again now?

Comment: Yes... I just had to reset it... the same query with different parameters worked all the time. only a specific params settings caused this to stuck